# Finding points that are almost the same in two lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a bunch of sets of points (longitudes/latitudes), where each set represents part of a discrete global grid. For each grid point, I am trying to find all the other grid points that are adjacent to it and therefore share at least one vertex. Most of the time the grid points line up perfectly and so I can usually find all the adjacent grids with a command like `any(i for i in point1 if i in point2)` (see MWE below).

Unfortunately, there seem to be some floating point precision errors in my dataset so there are cases where two vertices are *almost* identical, but not quite.

```
point1 = [(177.4150316259643, 80.06868164738896),
          (162.04772459076872, 80.29781125179436),
          (153.403148072541, 82.32650976966762),
          (165.2980351177718, 84.62501223785691),
          (-168.7499999978935, 83.98251402600364),
          (-168.74999999845744, 81.58268534624698)]

# point2[3] and point2[4] should match point1[0] and point1[5]
point2 = [(-157.50739908371222, 77.7317781763434),
          (-168.75000000105112, 76.80636446168572),
          (-179.99260091805525, 77.73177817832965),
          (177.41503162596428, 80.06868164738897),
          (-168.7500000015425, 81.58268534399583),
          (-154.91503162867107, 80.06868164543069)]

print(any([i for i in point1 if i in point2]))
# False

# adjust point2[3] so that it matches point1[0]
point2[3] = (177.4150316259643, 80.06868164738896)

print(any([i for i in point1 if i in point2]))
# True
```

Is there a computationally efficient way to solve this problem and find values that are *almost* the same, or the same within some tolerance?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that your code compares floating-point quantities for equality (`in` does a succession of `==` tests under the hood). And you can never reliably compare floats for equality. It's not a fault of your dataset but a consequence of the way floating-point works on real computers.

Comment: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
point1 = [(177.4150316259643, 80.06868164738896),
          (162.04772459076872, 80.29781125179436),
          (153.403148072541, 82.32650976966762),
          (165.2980351177718, 84.62501223785691),
          (-168.7499999978935, 83.98251402600364),
          (-168.74999999845744, 81.58268534624698)]

point2 = [(-157.50739908371222, 77.7317781763434),
          (-168.75000000105112, 76.80636446168572),
          (-179.99260091805525, 77.73177817832965),
          (177.41503162596428, 80.06868164738897),
          (-168.7500000015425, 81.58268534399583),
          (-154.91503162867107, 80.06868164543069)]


import numpy as np

# set tolerance to control how close values need to be 
# to be considered the same
tolerance = 10**(-6) 

p1 = np.array(point1)[:, np.newaxis, :]
p2 = np.array(point2)[np.newaxis, :, :]
(np.linalg.norm(p1 - p2, axis=2) < tolerance).nonzero()
```

This returns:

```
(array([0, 5]), array([3, 4]))
```

It means that `point1[0]` and `point2[3]` are close, and likewise for
`point1[5]` and `point2[4]`

If you just want to know if there are some close values you can replace the last line with:

```
(np.linalg.norm(p1 - p2, axis=2) < tolerance).any()
```

which gives:

```
True
```

Comment: I just wanted to add one additional point that was necessary to complete my problem due to the meridian at 180/-180, I converted the points from lon/lat to (x,y,z) coordinates and then applied @bb1's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with coordinates, you could just use a radius. You can set a threshold so that if another point falls within a certain radius, it will be considered similar.

```
def similar(point1, point2, threshold):
  return threshold^2 - (point1[0]-point2[0])^2 + (point1[1]-point2[1])^2 > 0
```

If true, they are almost the same, if false, they are not.